# How to solve this [deprecation] resolveActivity(Intent,int) in PackageManager has been deprecated (intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) != null;

Tags: package, package-managers

**I have the following below error occurring **

C:\FlutterDev\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_intent-2.0.2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\androidintent\IntentSender.java:87: warning: [deprecation] resolveActivity(Intent,int) in PackageManager has been deprecated
return packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) != null;
^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
1 error
1 warning

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':android_intent:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

```
If any knows about this error please guide
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to happen because the android_intent package is discontinued and replaced by the android_intent_plus package. try changing your package and choose the package version that matched your current SDK version.

https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus